# C++ reading a file in binary mode. Problems with END OF FILE

Tags: c++, linux, io, binaryfiles

I am learning C++and I have to read a file in binary mode. Here's how I do it (following the C++ reference):

```
unsigned values[255];
unsigned total;
ifstream in ("test.txt", ifstream::binary);

while(in.good()){
    unsigned val = in.get();
    if(in.good()){
        values[val]++;
        total++;
        cout << val <<endl;
    }
}

in.close();
```

So, I am reading the file byte per byte till `in.good()` is true. I put some `cout` at the end of the `while` in order to understand what's happening, and here is the output:

```
marco@iceland:~/workspace/huffman$ ./main 
97
97
97
97
10
98
98
10
99
99
99
99
10
100
100
10
101
101
10
221497852
marco@iceland:~/workspace/huffman$
```

Now, the input file "test.txt" is just:

```
aaaa
bb
cccc
dd
ee
```

So everything works perfectly till the end, where there's that 221497852. I guess it's something about the end of file, but I can't figure the problem out.

I am using gedit & g++ on a debian machine(64bit).
Any help help will be appreciated.

Many thanks,

Marco

Comment: Please post the solution as an actual answer and accept it, rather than editing it into the *question*. Also, don't put "SOLVED" in the title. Just mark a question as accepted. :)

Comment: ok, i didn't know how to do that. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've eventually figured this out.
Apparently it seems the problem wasn't due to any code. The problem was gedit. It always appends a newline character at the end of file. This also happen with other editors, such as vim. For some editor this can be configured to not append anything, but in gedit this is apparently not possible. https://askubuntu.com/questions/13317/how-to-stop-gedit-gvim-vim-nano-from-adding-end-of-file-newline-char

Cheers to everyone who asked me,

Marco

Answer (score 5):

[`fstream::get`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) returns an `int`-value. This is one of the problems.

Secondly, you are reading in **binary**, so you shouldn't use formatted streams. You should use [`fstream::read`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/):

```
// read a file into memory
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream

int main () {

  std::ifstream is ("test.txt", std::ifstream::binary);
  if (is) {
    // get length of file:
    is.seekg (0, is.end);
    int length = is.tellg();
    is.seekg (0, is.beg);

    char * buffer = new char [length];

    std::cout << "Reading " << length << " characters... ";
    // read data as a block:
    is.read (buffer,length);

    if (is)
      std::cout << "all characters read successfully.";
    else
      std::cout << "error: only " << is.gcount() << " could be read";
    is.close();

    // ...buffer contains the entire file...

    delete[] buffer;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `get()` is unformatted, according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get ?

Comment: aren't chars actually integers? What is the problem if I'm using get and assigning its return values to an unsigned int variable?

Comment: Well, it's not that easy. `char` can either be `signed` or `unsigned` by default, and if you use unsigned you cannot obtain such values as `-1` which might indicate `eof` (system-dependent)

Comment: This answer is simply incorrect.  The OP's code is not idiomatic, and doesn't use `istream::get()` the way I think it was meant to be used, but I don't see anything that would make it not work, unless `istream::get()` returned a negative value when it hadn't encountered end of file.

Comment: @bash.d But he's not using the return value to test for end of file.  It's not idiomatic, _but_ the standard does say that if there is no character to extract, `istream::get()` should set `failbit`.  (I would also expect it to set `eofbit`, under the more general definition of `eofbit`.)

Comment: Which answer is simply incorrect?? This is what I stated, not to use `fstream::get` like this.

Comment: Actually I think am using the return value to check the eof. In fact, right after the reading with get(), I coded if(in.good()) that, as the reference says, "Returns true if none of the stream's error state flags (eofbit, failbit and badbit) is set." http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/

Comment: You should check for `eofbit` explicitly!

Comment: @bash.d You should almost never check for `eofbit`.  Only _after_ input has failed, to know whether it failed because you'd reached end of file, or whether it failed because of a format error.

Comment: @bash.d That the fact that `istream::get()` returns an `int` is part of the problem.  That he should use `istream::read()` if the file is binary.  Your example code isn't a very good example either.

Comment: @MarcoGalassi You're not using the return value of `istream::get()` to test for end of file.  You're using the internal state of the `istream`.  Both should work, but when using `istream::get()` (rather than `istream::get( char& )`), assigning the return value to an `int`, then comparing that with `EOF`, is the idiomatic way of doing things.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the way `istream::get()` was designed to be used.
The classical idiom for using this function would be:

```
for ( int val = in.get(); val != EOF; val = in.get() ) {
    //  ...
}
```

or even more idiomatic:

```
char ch;
while ( in.get( ch ) ) {
    //  ...
}
```

The first loop is really inherited from C, where `in.get()` is
the equivalent of `fgetc()`.

Still, as far as I can tell, the code you give *should* work.
It's not idiomatic, and it's not

The C++ standard is unclear what it should return if the
character value read is negative.  `fgetc()` requires a value in
the range `[0...UCHAR_MAX]`, and I think it safe to assume that
this is the *intent* here.  It is, at least, what every
implementation I've used does.  But this doesn't affect your
input.  Depending on how the implementation interprets the
standard, the return value of `in.get()` must be in the range
`[0...UCHAR_MAX]` or `[CHAR_MIN...CHAR_MAX]`, or it must be EOF
(typically -1).  (The reason I'm fairly sure that the intent is
to require `[0...UCHAR_MAX]` is because otherwise, you may not
be able to distinguish end of file from a valid character.)

*And* if the return value is EOF (almost always
-1), `failbit` should be set, so `in.good()` would return
`false`.  There is *no* case where `in.get()` would be allowed
to return 221497852.  The only explication I can possibly think
of for your results is that your file has some character with
bit 7 set at the end of the file, that the implementation is
returning a negative number for this (but not end of file,
because it is a character), which results in an out of bounds
index in `values[val]`, and that this out of bounds index
somehow ends up modifying `val`.  Or that your implementation is
broken, and is not setting `failbit` when it returns end of
file.

To be certain, I'd be interested in knowing what you get from
the following:

```
std::ifstream in( "text.txt", std::ios_base::binary );
int ch = in.get();
while ( ch != std::istream::traits_type::eof() ) {
    std::cout << ch << std::endl;
    ch = in.get();
}
```

This avoids any issues of a possibly invalid index, and any type
conversions (although the conversion `int` to `unsigned` is well
defined).  Also, out of curiosity (since I can only access VC++
here), you might try replacing `in` as follows:

```
std::istringstream in( "\n\xE5" );
```

I would expect to get:

```
10
233
```

(Assuming 8 bit bytes and an ASCII based code set.  Both of
which are almost, but not quite universal today.)

Comment: I've tried your code above and the resulting output is: none :D

By the way. I tried to change my code substituting endl with '\n'.
Now the output is almost the same, except the last number, which is now 10(the ASCII '\n' character).
So i now guess it's something about the endl. Anyway i still can't understand what is the last 10 character, since the file has no \n at the end.

Comment: @MarcoGalassi There's something else going on that you're not showing us.  The code above was copy/pasted from a program which compiles and runs on my machine, and works; I've done almost exactly the same thing in the past with g++.  And whether you use `'\n'` or `std::endl` only affects whether you flush the output immediately.

Comment: There is nothing more.. That's the code. I'm compiling using g++ main.cpp -o main and running the program with ./main
I think there is somekind of issue from the end of file. I also read about endl which is supposed to be a \n with flushing, and that's why I can't understand the output changes. What machine are you using? Linux, Windows? What architecture? (I'm trying to check all the differences)

Comment: @MarcoGalassi The machine here, on which I just checked, is a Windows machine, but I've done exactly the same thing on Linux boxes and Sun Sparcs (under Solaris) in the past.  If the third block of code I posted doesn't work, there's something wrong with your installation.  (I've just run it under Windows, after carefully creating a file with Unix line endings and no last eol, and I get the output you got through the second 101, then nothing.)

Comment: When you talk about "something wrong with your installation", what are you referring at? g++? debian installation? or whetever

Comment: @MarcoGalassi I don't know.  Probably g++.  (I could be something like the headers you compile against being from a different version of the library than what you link against.)  If I can remember and find time, I'll recheck it on my Linux machine tonight, but the third loop, simply wrapped in `main`, should work.  If it doesn't, then there's no point in analysing your code further, since there is a problem in the installation itself.